# My hp laptop doesn't shut down?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have hp envy x360 laptop, and I have some issues in powering off the laptop.
When I click power off or shut down button by mouse,the laptop doesn't power off and it only shut down after I press the power button for 5 seconds.
This problem affected the laptop battery, now if I fully powered off the laptop and left it for 2 days it discharged by itself.

The battery is built-in
Any help to fix these issues?

Comment: I mean it enter the mode like standby mode, although I click on shut down.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which Windows version?

Comment: If Windows, run [powercfg -energy](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/976034/guided-help-get-a-detailed-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-for-you) and post the report.

Comment: Operating system= Windows 10 home.

Comment: Waiting for the powercfg energy report. (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc     https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dHA1f7t1lPsL8lI_N8WcU9t46DXkNT_-

Answer (score 1):

According to the energy report, a USB device has sleep problems.
According to the device id, this is most likely a USB flash disk/stick.

I suggest to disconnect any USB device possible, then test shutdown again.

If this test comes up negative and the problem device seems not to be a USB disk,
and if you have a USB keyboard and/or mouse, as a further test disconnect them as well
and power off (if required) by a short press of the power button.

Comment: Yes when I unplugged the usb mouse before shutting down the laptop,now it shut down correctly.but while it is in power off state why the battery discharged by itself?

Comment: Windows 10 has hybrid sleep, where the computer never totally sleeps. I suggest to start the Device Manager, open Human Interface Devices, right-click the mouse, select Properties, tab Power Management, and check if "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is checked. If not, set to checked and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem:

Go to Device Manager.
Expand System Devices and find Intel Management Engine Interface.
Go to its properties. Click on Power Management.
Untick "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power.

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Power-Light-Won-t-Turn-Off-After-Shutdown/td-p/6588252/page/2

Comment: Maybe a setting in the BIOS/UEFI allows USB ports to be powered after shutting down the computer, which would cause the battery to be depleted even if the PC is turned off. It's called Always-On USB on my old Lenovo laptop, but it could be called something else at HP.